# How to use PUSHD and POPD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am getting an "UNC path not supported" error while trying to get files from a shared network drive.

My research tells me that `pushd` and `popd` may help, but I can't figure out how to use them correctly.

What are good usage examples for `pushd` and `popd`?

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
C:
dir
pause

rem ----- using pushd to other path

pushd Users
dir
pause 

rem ----- using popd to exit current pushd directory
popd
dir
pause
```

Comment: thank you for replying, it makes more sense to me now :)

Answer (score 0):

The remarks about popd given in [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/popd) is misleading. It says "*If you use the popd command, the directory on the top of the stack is removed from the stack and the current directory is changed to that directory.*". But actually the current directory changes to the directory currently on the top of the stack.